# How do I loop through JavaScript objects in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have 4 JavaScript objects that I need to loop through in D3. I need to show a graph for each object. The JSON looks like this:

```
[
{
    "name": "Sample 1",
    "embed": 10,
    "interactive": 10,
    "rapidDev": 7,
    "support": 7,
    "predictive": 4,
    "modelDev": 3,
    "cost": 2
},
{
    "name": "Sample 2",
    "embed": 7,
    "interactive": 6,
    "rapidDev": 7,
    "support": 7,
    "predictive": 4,
    "modelDev": 3,
    "cost": 10
},
{
    "name": "Sample 3",
    "embed": 10,
    "interactive": 10,
    "rapidDev": 2,
    "support": 2,
    "predictive": 2,
    "modelDev": 2,
    "cost": 10
},
{
    "name": "Sample 4",
    "embed": 2,
    "interactive": 7,
    "rapidDev": 7,
    "support": 7,
    "predictive": 10,
    "modelDev": 3,
    "cost": 8
}
]
```

Each "name" is the name of a software title, while each other key is a numerical rating. I need to display the ratings for each title like so:
 [image: Graphs]

My code currently generates 4 SVGs, and each SVG has a title above it, but then I'm stumped. If I can get the arcs to show up for each rating, then I can take it from there. I just can't get the arcs to show up in the SVG. Can someone help me with the code below after the "var svg" code and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```
d3.json("js/tools.json", function(error, data) {
                        var tau = Math.PI *1.5,
                            width = "250",
                            height = "250",
                            innerRadius = 100,
                            outerRadius = 120,
                            i;

                        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                            .range(["#eec947", "#9b7560", "#76b7b1", "#f28e2c", "#fe9da6", "#bab1ac"]);

                        var arc = d3.arc()
                          .innerRadius(innerRadius-i)
                          .outerRadius(outerRadius-i)
                          .startAngle(0);

                        color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "name"; }));

                        data.forEach(function(d, index) {
                            d.ratings = color.domain().map(function(name) {
                                return {name: name, rating: +d[name]};
                            });
                        var i = (outerRadius - innerRadius)*(index + 1) + index*3;
                        var heading = d3.select(".toolCharts").append("h4").text(d.name);
                        var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll(".toolCharts")
                            .data(data)
                            .append("svg")
                            .attr("class", "chart")
                            .attr("width", width)
                            .attr("height", height)
                            .append("g")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

                        var g = svg.selectAll('.arc')
                            .data(function(d){return arc(d.ratings);})
                            .enter()
                            .append("g");

                        var background = g.append("path")
                            .datum({endAngle: tau})
                            .classed("bg", true)
                            .style("fill", "#ddd")
                            .attr("d", arc);
                        var foreground = g.append("path")
                            .data(function(d){ return d.rating/10 * tau})
                            .classed("arc", true)
                            .style("fill", function(d) {return color(i); })
                            .attr("d", arc);
                        var label = g.append("text")
                            .attr("x", -10)
                            .attr("y", -outerRadius + i + 20)
                            .style("text-anchor", "end")
                            .text(d.ratings.name);

                        });

                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first instinct would be to make a wrapper function so that a separate `d3.arc()` generator was made for each of the tools listed in the json. I didn't quite understand what you did for your `outerRadius - innerRadius` but my (admittedly hacky...) alternative was to just make a scale specific to each of the tools listed in the json.

Here is a block showing my attempt, I hope it is helpful: https://bl.ocks.org/beemyfriend/b9b0a013362bfc0cefa43f7bbb8d403d

Comment: Here is your code with OPs colour scale: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/f46119c8123d2bec11023dd2f2d0f77e

Comment: I actually didn't know that domains default to index if no domain was provided. It's cool learning something new on a comment of an answer I provided!

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks!